# All xcode project files highlighted with "i" character

Tags: xcode

All the files highlighted with "i" and all group expand when open the project. Anyone help me!

[image]

Comment: You have typed "i" into the filter box (below the tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check down the project you have [image: typed] the letter i that have filtered the project files for you that contains letter i just focus on the text field and remove the searched text